# Как выйти из цикла while?

Tags: c#

Не получается выйти из цикла while

```
public void SingleNumber(int result)
        {
            bool t = true;

            while (t)
            {
                List<int> usedNums = new List<int>();
                usedNums.Add(result);

                if (usedNums.Count > 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < usedNums.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (usedNums[i] == result)
                        {
                            t = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                int newRes = result;

                string stroka = newRes.ToString();
                char[] num = stroka.ToCharArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < num.Length; j++)
                    {
                        int b = num[i] - '0';
                        int b1 = num[j] - '0';
                        if (i >= 1)
                        {
                            result += b1 * b1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result = b * b + b1 * b1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(result);

                if (result == 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        List<int> usedNums = new List<int>();
        while (t)
        {
            usedNums.Add(result);
```